# Как объединить значения в списке

Tags: python, list, словари

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне объединить значения из списка?
Я имею следующие значения:

```
vacancy_details['key_skills']

[{'name': 'Навыки продаж'}, {'name': 'Обучение и развитие'}]
<class 'list'>
```

Как мне их объединить, чтобы было следующее:

```
['Навыки продаж', 'Обучение и развитие']
```

Самое интересное, что

```
vacancy_details['key_skills'].values() # не работает
```

Буду очень благодарен любой помощи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vacancy_details = {'key_skills': [{'name': 'Навыки продаж'}, {'name': 'Обучение и развитие'}]}
out = [d['name'] for d in vacancy_details['key_skills']]
print(out)
```

```
['Навыки продаж', 'Обучение и развитие']
```